# Swift Sorting parse results by createdAt

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I query messages stored on parse.com

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    query.whereKey("sender", equalTo: self.sender)
    query.whereKey("receiver", equalTo: self.receiver)
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            var messages = [Int: [AnyObject]]()

            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                var i: Int = 0
                for object in objects {

                    var temp = [AnyObject]()

                    temp.append(object["sender"]!)
                    temp.append(object["receiver"]!)
                    temp.append(object.createdAt!)
                    temp.append(object["message"]!)

                    messages[i] = temp

                    i = i+1
                }
                print("Messages: \(messages)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Error!")
        }
    }
```

The result looks like

> Messages: [2: [Phil, Eff, 2015-08-27 15:05:04 +0000, three], 0: [Phil, Eff, 2015-08-27 15:04:57 +0000, one], 1: [Phil, Eff, 2015-08-27 15:05:00 +0000, two]]

It seems like `query.orderByAscending("createdAt")` is doing nothing?

Comment: what happens when you `println(objects)` under `if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {`

Comment: it is giving the the sorted result - okay. Why is the messages dictionary empty then?

Answer (score 1):

`createdAt` is doing what it's intended to do. It's how your adding the data to you object.

You need to forego the int var and simply use :

```
messages = temp
```

, because you are running a loop for every object in objects. Each message can only equal it's counterpart, no reason to specify an index for it

To add your message to an array simply do the following:

```
var messagesArray:NSMutableArray = []

..findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {

      if let object = objects as ? [PFObject] {
           for object in objects {
           ...
           messages = temp
           self.messagesArray.addObject(messages)
           ...
```

Comment: If I do this, the loop overrides `messages` each time and at the end I just have the last entry

Comment: That's because your not doing anything with it @PhilHarmonie  Add the message to an `NSMutableArray` and println the array instead of each object. Right now your retrieving objects from Parse in array (objects) your dissecting that array by running a loop to get each value you desire. Now, adding it to an NSMutableArray you'll be able to access that NSMutableArray outside of the call back for use elsewhere

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. Could you update the code for better understanding?